# Workaround for no default browser on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to use [Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).browse() to invoke a URL, this works fine on Windows machines or on Linux machines with a default browser configured.  However, it throws an IOException exception when no default browser is found on Linux.  What are some of the ways to work around this?  I suppose I can attempt to launch Firefox and assume its there but I do not want to make that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) or just try with konqueror  (default on KDE, but not supported by Desktop API) and firefox.

Try also kmclient exec url.

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
   desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
   // blah blah
} else {
   // try to launch xdg-open
   // or try launching other browsers?
}
```

Comment: xdg-open uses kfmclient on KDE (which in turn will open konqueror if that's default), so there's no reason to open either konqueror or kfmclient directly.

Comment: I will try xdg-open for now, if it runs into further problems then I'll take the route of setting a configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

You can allow the user to enter the command they want to launch their browser, and then save that command so it will use that command everytime.

Comment: using x-www-browser or www-browser as a default is a safe bet.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's much you could do beyond:

1. Check in common locations for common browsers (firefox, mozilla, etc.)
2. Iterate the PATH environment variable looking for common browser executables.
3. Ask the user in configuration.

Additionally, there is a [whole section of the SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#whatisbrowser) dedicated to discovering the appropriate version of firefox to use on a particular system (keep reading the questions starting with the one linked above.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try various browsers in some order -- firefox, opera, etc, etc; also keep an editable configuration file which lets the user set a browser, remember there the one you found, etc.

Comment: Good idea!
I would say that most users use only the popular browsers, and there aren't many of those.. So by making a list of 20 browsers, your chances of missing in such a test are slim. This test should be carried after you get this IOException.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Desktop.browse() ultimately calls XDesktopPeer.browse() on *ix.  That method [is implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/classes/sun/awt/X11/XDesktopPeer.java) by calling [gnome_url_show](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libgnome/stable/libgnome-gnome-url.html#gnome-url-show).  That probably works fine in some cases, but xdg-open is the cross-platform solution, as others have noted.

Arguably, this is a bug in Sun Java.  [Bug 6490730](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6490730), "Desktop throws IOException instead of showing URL or sending mail", (reported November 2006) seems relevant

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute `xdg-open http://the/url` *first* if you're going to implement one of the "cycle through a bunch of browsers". That should [open the default browser](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) if for some reason Java can't find it. (It does seem likely that this is what Java does anyway.)

Comment: Surprisingly, Java doesn't use xdg-open.  See the source linked in my answer.